# laravel 5 cant save image

Tags: laravel-5, intervention

When trying to save an image on my server, in my laravel 5 project with intervention image class, with the following code :

```
$pathFull = public_path('images/original/brand/' . $filename);
$img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
$img->encode('jpg')->save($pathFull);
```

I get the error:

```
NotWritableException in Image.php line 138:
Can't write image data to path  
(/var/www/mydomain.com/public/images/original/brand/nanan.jpg)
```

So ive changed permission on the folder (that already exists) with:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/mydomain.com/public/images
```

Ive checked the permissions they are 775 so that command works. I tried it localy (xampp) and it worked fine and the driectory paths are fine. I keep getting this error only if i use 777 i don't but thats danerous.

What else can I try to keep the server save and not use 777?

Comment: @maytham the pictures dont need to be protected why should i use routes for the images than?

Comment: @mayham but than i need to create unnecesary routes using 775 on public should be perfectly safe.

Comment: If you think that is the way to go, that's fine dude, was just a suggestion.

Comment: @maytham thanks for the suggestion i might use it but it doesnt explain why I cant write at the moment. and i really like to find out what i did wrong so i can avoid it in the future

Comment: have you solved this issue yet? I have check your code and it should works fine if your public folder is welling to have write permission as your problem occur, so I do not suspect your code, I do only suspect some thing with write permission in your system/folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the paths are not the same. Check it out. See the **original** directory?

```
$pathFull = public_path('images/brand/thumb/' . $filename);

Can't write image data to path  
(/var/www/mydomain.com/public/images/original/brand/nanan.jpg)

sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/mydomain.com/public/images/original/brand
```

I have made recently a method like yours. It works fine for me. Here it is:

```
$image = Input::file('image');
$filename = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
$path = public_path('images/' . Auth::user()->email . '/' . $filename);
$img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
$img->encode('jpg')->save($path);
```

Comment: sorry images/brand/thumb/ was wrong (bad copy paste). I dont see much difference in the second part of code or am i overlooking something?

Comment: ;) no you are not overlooking... I tried to imitate your code and test it in my app. For me it is working fine.